# How to scale Azure VM Cores

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, cpu

I have a Python code that I need to run on 1000 CSVs in parallel computing to do calculations. One CPU core can finish running the code over each CSV in 8 hours.

Thus I am looking for a way to use Azure for this. I would like to create several virtual machines, say 4x D5v2 with 16 cores each to access a Windows Server that runs on a 64 Cores machine.

I tried to create these VMs in the same Cloud Service and I put them into the same Availability Set, which worked fine. When all VMs are running and I access any one of those VMs, I see that the cores on all other VMs are allocated to "Other Roles".

My questions are:

1) Is it possible to create a hypothetical VM out of 4 VMs to use more cores?

2) How can I manually allocate all cores in the Cloud Service to one specific VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is it possible to create a hypothetical VM out of 4 VMs to use more cores?

No you can not.

2) How can I manually allocate all cores in the Cloud Service to one specific VM?

You can not do this. You need to use a cloud native solution to scale your process over multiple resources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Are you aware of any other cloud solutions where 1) would be possible or where it would be possible to use Windows Server with 64+ Cores?

Comment: Yes it would, you can not split one application over multiple computers. However using the resources on one big one can probably do the trick. Otherwise you need to split the input in smaller pieces and run them over different computers

Answer (score 3):

Your best solution would be to use [Azure Batch](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/batch/) With Batch you create a job, and it will run on as many CPU's as you specify it can run on.

Taken from the Batch front page

> When you are ready to run a job, Batch starts a pool of compute virtual machines for you, installing applications and staging data, running jobs with as many tasks as you have, identifying failures and re-queuing work and scaling down the pool as work completes. You have control over scale to meet deadlines, manage costs, and run at the right scale for your application.

Comment: Thank you! Will look into Azure Batch.